# Showing existence of a field extension of degree $n$ for a finite field $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

EDIT: Just mentioning that this is a homework question.

This is my first time posting a question on math.stackexchange, so I hope you find it in your hearts to forgive any stylistic or rule transgressions I make. I have searched through quite a few of the similar threads that popped up but nothing answered my question.

The problem is as the title suggests; given a finite field $F$ and some $n > 0$, show that it has a finite field extension of degree $n$.

My attempt at a solution is as follows:

Let $|F| = p^{m}$.

Consider the splitting field of $x^{p^{mn}}-x$ over the integers modulo $p$ for some prime $p$; call it $G$. This is a finite field of order $p^{mn}$. Then it contains a subfield of size $p^{m}$, say $G'$. This is isomorphic to $F$. However, I am pretty sure $G$ does not constitute an extension of $F$.

I have tried constructing a field extension of $F$ isomorphic to $G$ by considering the image of a map $\varphi: G \rightarrow Im(\varphi)$ such that $\varphi$ restricted to G' is the isomorphism from $G$ to $F$, but I hit a wall there in showing that it was an isomorphism (briefly, I consider a n-basis for $G$ and tried defining it accordingly but wasn't able to complete it because I could not prove bijectivity).

If it is not too much trouble, I would simply prefer a tiny hint that pushes me in a promising direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not look at a splitting field of $x^{p^{nm}} - x$ over $F$?

Comment: I am currently looking for a blunt object to strike myself with, but in the meantime, thank you, I see it clearly now - existence, extension, Tower Law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think $\,G\,$ doesn't constitute an extension of your original $\,F\,$? Because it actually is, or perhaps more formally: $\,G\,$ is a vector space of dimension $\,mn\,$ over the prime field of characteristic $\,p\,\,,\,\Bbb F_p\,$ , and $\,F\,$ is a linear space of dimension $\,m\,$ over the same prime subfield.

Let $K\leq G\,$ be a subfield of dimension $\,m\,$ over $\,\Bbb F_p\,$ . But it's not hard to show both $\,H\,\,,\,F$ are splitting  fields over $\,\Bbb F_p\,$ of the same polynomial, namely $\,x^{p^m}-x\in\Bbb F_p[x]\,$ and, thus, they're isomorphic *as fields*, not only as vector spaces of the same dimension over the same field.

We, in fact, have just passed above over one of the proofs (or *the* proof) that there's only one field of a given finite cardinality u[p to isomorphism.

Well, there you have your extension of $\,F\,$...which, in fact, **you** did find.

**Added:** I couldn't see how to give "just a hint" as the OP already solved the problem. What was lacking is to get her/him convinced that she/he actually did solve the problem and, hopefully, the above will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I am not disputing your correctness - my only issue is that I seem to have a gap in accepting this notion of "up to isomorphism". I understand $F$ and $G$ are isomorphic splitting fields. My instructor has been pretty over the map with how they use "is" and "unique up to isomorphism" in class - might be the source of my confusion.

However, even if isomorphic, why is an extension of one necessarily an extension of the other?I might be pedantic with details, but I am not seeing how the extension of an isomorphic copy of $F$ is itself an actual extension of $F$.

Comment: Hmmm....do you accept that if $\,F\,$ is a field and $\,f(x)\in F[x]\,$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $\,\geq 1\,$, then *the field* $\,K:=F[x]/(f(x))\,$ is an extension of $\,F\,$? Because if you do, and the above is one of the most basic and elementary theorems in fields extensions, then it is basically the same argument: one has that we can *embed* $\,F\,$ into $\,K\,$ via $\,a\to a+(f(x))\in K\,$, which is an injective ring homomorphism and etc.

Comment: Yes the first theorem guarantees the existence of a field extension given an irreducible polynomial.

Okay, I see what you mean... the theorem proves the existence of a field extension by viewing the image of F under that embedding as being F contained in the extension.

So extension in this context means what you have defined; is this necessarily equivalent to the definition of an extension using the intersection?

Comment: What intersection are you talking about? Unless you talk of *the* splitting field (of a family of polynomials over a field) as the intersection of all the extension fields that contain all the roots of all the polynomials, I'm not sure I follow you...and if you meant this then yes: in your particular case it is pretty easy to show that the above mentioned intersection **has** to be the field $\,\Bbb F_{p^{nm}}\,$ as it has the minimal ammount of elements required to be a splitting field for $\,x^{p^{nm}}-x\in\Bbb F_p[x]\,$...

Comment: I meant something else but I realize that it was irrelevant. I think I have a clearer picture now. Thanks for your patience with my dumb questions, it really helped.

One last item: in all contexts from here on out, when we say a field $F'$ is an extension of another field $F$,  we are actually saying that $F$ embeds into $F'$; $F'$ does not necessarily actually contain the actual elements of $F$, correct? For example, if $K \cong G$ and $F$ is a field containing $G$, then am I valid in saying that $F$ is an extension of $K$ as well?

Comment: Well, yes as long as the embedding is as rings (fields), and as long as this is made precise, which it usually is in most books I  can right now remember of. And your questions are anything but dumb. In fact, some of them made me re-think my concepts and that's nice.